# How on dask-woker how to share mutiple file and folder so that not getting module error

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

````
```return pickle.loads(x)
````

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src.data_processing'
Exception ignored in: <function Pool.**del** at 0x7f593e7a95e0>

Comment: did you mean to add code ?

Comment: yes, but in the form project structure not using upload_file for single file upload

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you have a custom module. It really needs to be installed and available on the workers so it needs to be added in the image used to spin up the Dask cluster. This depends on what type of Dask cluster you are using (Kubernetes, ECS, etc) and if the cluster is ephemeral or long-running.

If they have access to a private repo with this module, you could try the PipInstall Worker plug-ins [here](https://distributed.dask.org/en/stable/plugins.html#built-in-worker-plugins)